# Moving two lines in opposite directions via CSS3 animations

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-animations

I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/xuj0uu2k/4/

Markup

```
<div class="lline"></div>
<div class="projekt"><h1>SERVICES</h1></div>
<div class="rline"></div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes anima {
    from {width: 0%; }
    to { width: 40%; }
}

.lline { 
    margin-top: 20px; 
    width: 40%; 
    background-color: #333; 
    animation-name: anima; 
    animation-duration:1s; 
    height: 2px; 
    float: left; }

.projekt { 
    text-align: center; 
    width: 14%; 
    margin: 0 auto; }

.rline { 
    margin-top: -38px;
    width: 40%; 
    background-color: #333; 
    animation-name: anima; 
    animation-duration:1s; 
    height: 2px;  
    float: right; }
```

I need to animate the two lines from the text `SERVICES` to its borders.

I tried to set it up with `animation-direction` property, but it didn't work. The lines must be responsive, so I have to use some mediaqueries, but if you know better way to do it, I'll be glad. Thank you

Comment: Please do not circumvent the quality filter.

Comment: Thank you, Fabrizio. I need to animate the lines in the reverse direction as it works in the example (not working in Opera and Safari)

Comment: Wait for the re-opening of your question and please take into account the @BoltClock suggestion for the your next question

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: From what I gather of the issue (prefixing) - then this would be a dupe. For example, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xuj0uu2k/8/)

Comment: yes but this is not responsive and lines overlap the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with less markup using pseudoelements and `display: flex`, like in this example: http://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/aObYLK

Markup

```
<h1 class="animateheading">SERVICES</h1>
```

Css

```
.animateheading {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

/* lines */
.animateheading:before,
.animateheading:after {
   content: "";
   flex-grow: 1;
   height: 1px;
   min-width: 100px;
   border-top: 1px #333 solid;
}

/* animation toward left */
.animateheading:before { 
   margin-right: .3em; 
   -webkit-animation: lineleft 3s linear 1s forwards; 
   -moz-animation: lineleft 3s linear 1s forwards; 
   animation: lineleft 3s linear 1s forwards; 
}

/* animation toward right */
.animateheading:after  { 
   margin-left: .3em;
   -webkit-animation: lineright 3s linear 1s forwards; 
   -moz-animation: lineright 3s linear 1s forwards; 
   animation: lineright 3s linear 1s forwards; 
} 


/* keyframes for left animation */ 
@-webkit-keyframes lineleft {
   from { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); }
   to { -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

@-moz-keyframes lineleft {
   from { -moz-transform: translate(0, 0); }
   to { -moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

@keyframes lineleft {
   from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
   to { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

/* keyframes for right animation */ 
@-webkit-keyframes lineright {
   from { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); }
   to { -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0); }
}

@-moz-keyframes lineright {
   from { -moz-transform: translate(0, 0); }
   to { -moz-transform: translate(100%, 0); }
}

@keyframes lineright {
   from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
   to { transform: translate(100%, 0); }
}
```

Just some notes about this implementation

- `Flexbox` position could require several different syntaxes, due to its implementation across browser: see http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox; since it is applied on pseudoelements only for styling purpose, a lack of support can be considered as *graceful degradation*;
- This code works with text of any length and on every `viewport` size, since it animates the `transform` property using a percentage value. No matter how many rows will take the text, the lines will be always vertically centered;
- Add as many vendor prefixes as you need for the `keyframes`;
- The `animation-fill-mode` property is set to forwards so the last animation frame will be retained (and the lines don't come back).
- If you need to always see two lines, even for really long texts, set a `min-width` on pseudoelements as I did in the example, otherwise you may safely remove it.